# What is the best way to process DNS packets with DPDK?

Tags: dns, dpdk

Edit : I am using DPDK version DPDK 21.11.2 (LTS)

I'm working on implementing a DPDK based DNS server. I have researched and studied both concepts. In my understanding, we are bypassing the kernel with DPDK and thus losing all the processing ability of the kernel. DPDK is limited till Layer 2, as the NIC we bind to it loses its IP. To implement layer 3 protocol, is l3fwd the best option?

I read up on KNI as well, as it shows a simple command to assign IP. But that is no longer available in latest versions

Basically what I want to do is, send a DNS packet to the DPDK NIC (via another VM). This current DPDK VM then processes it and send a answer packet back through the same NIC. What is the least complicated way to do this?

I have only tried basic DPDK examples like basicfwd and l2fwd where simple packets are sent and received by the same VM.

Comment: The query is incomplete, that there is no mention of DPDK version, whether processing of DNS packet is done in userspace code or by kernel network stack is not clear, if it is usersapce code there is no code snippet to show case the issue. For me this look like more of suggestion ask rather than any issue. Is this right?

Comment: This may help, at least as an example: https://github.com/alandtsang/mydpdkdns

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I have been referring to this. But this is based on dpdk 17, which is old and uses kni, which like I mentioned is not available in later versions

Comment: @VipinVarghese I have only changed pieces of code in the github example also mentioned here. I want to do processing in userspace ultimately, but have no idea how to get started . Yes I was looking for suggestions

Comment: @user20292824 please post the changes, please post the DPDk version planned to use, from your explanation `what I want to do is, send a DNS packet to the DPDK NIC (via another VM)` it is not clear what you are asking. is it suggestion for how to transfer packet between VM efficiently or asking about how create DNS response (which already have a github reference). Your query is not clear.

Comment: @user20292824 waiting for your reply and update in the question to clarify whether you are looking for DNS processing or VM to VM transfer. Please update with error logs, code snippet and minimum reproducible code too.

Comment: @user20292824 any updates on sharing information,

Comment: @VipinVarghes I have gone back to the basics of dpdk, and understood that in order to implement my desired architecture, I need to implement a TCP/IP stack using Fstack. I wasn't looking for help with my code but rather a suggestion on sending/receiving a DNS packet via DPDK-binded NIC.

Comment: @user20292824 thank you for confirming, please update the question with new findings and close the question if it is not required.